# What are the statistics of HTML vs. Text email usage

Tags: email

What the latest figures are on people viewing their emails in text only mode vs. HTML?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html_email) and it's [source](http://www.emaillabs.com/tools/email-marketing-statistics.html) both seem to reference [this](http://www.dmnews.com/Outlook-2006-More-Technology-More-Targeting/article/90305/) research from 2006 which is an eternity ago in internet terms.

An issue with combining both HTML and text based emails is taking a disproportionate amount of time to resolve given the likely number of users it is affecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with web browser usage statistics, it depends entirely on the audience.

I have access to a bit of data on this subject and it seems that text-only email use is very low (for non-technical audiences, at least). <0.1% up to ~6% depending on demographic.

It's not *that* much effort to do both (especially if you can find something to help you do the heavy lifting when creating multipart MIME containers), and you can always write a script to generate text from your HTML or something.

Comment: Text email usage has been dropping steadily for quite a while. However, last I saw, the Apple Watch only shows the text version, so it may make a comeback. Or, maybe people will wait until they're on appropriately sized devices.